# Google Cloud DNS; base domain name redirect

Tags: dns

Is there a way to alias the base domain name to another domain name with Google DNS?  I.e google.com has the alisa of www.google.com, just the base domain not the www.

Reason; 
Our site is coded with urls's that point to google.com now all of our links are broken. This all happend after our provider was purchased, domain maintenance was scheduled and completed.   Our provider says google can do this?  But,  I know that "A" records cannot, and "Cname" records cannot.   Is there a way to do this with Google Cloud DNS.

Comment: "redirect" and "DNS" can not stand in the same sentence as there is no concept of "redirection" in the DNS. A redirection is an HTTP thing. The DNS maps names to IP addresses for the specific problem you have in hand. As soon as the traffic then hits a specific IP address then the webserver listening here should be properly configured to reply to the HTTP request by either delivering some content or doing an HTTP redirection to another URL. So in short you always have two things to configure: the DNS part and the HTTP part.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but cname is a way to alias one name to another.  Redirect is a bad way to ask the question.   Is there a way to alias the top level or base domain to a different domain name the way Cname does?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error.  I amended my question to properly reflect my problem.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? Are you saying you have site links that actually point to google.com, and google changed their URLs, or is something else going on?

Comment: " Is there a way to alias the top level or base domain to a different domain name the way Cname does?" yes, but not in the DNS standard since a CNAME record can not happen at the apex because of the NS and SOA records. So some providers are giving you alternate options that basically work out like a CNAME, just called differently. But it is not standard, so different with each provider. Sometimes it is called ALIAS, sometimes ANAME, sometimes even abusing CNAME at apex, etc. ..

Comment: Look at https://serverfault.com/questions/617248/does-google-domains-support-cname-like-functionality-at-the-zone-apex/714357 this seems to be directly your question. But note the date, things could have changed since then, I do not know. A search will provide you many answers, you are not the only one in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Google allows an A record for whole domain with potentially multiple addresses, but not CNAME.

[Google explanation](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290350?hl=en#zippy=%2Chost-name%2Ctype-of-resource-record)